# How to save php variable into a 2D java script array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, 2d

How do I save php variable into a 2D JavaScript array. 
inside php file :

```
for ($i=0;$i<$max;$i++) {
 $needHelp1[$i];
 $needHelp2[$i];
 }
```

I need to save the `$needHelp1[$i]` and `$needHelp2[$i]`to java script 2Darray called `var needHelp = []` which is inside the same php file.

```
[ $needHelp1[0] , $needHelp2[1] 
  $needHelp1[1] , $needHelp2[1]
  $needHelp1[2] , $needHelp2[1] 
  $needHelp1[3] , $needHelp2[1] ]
```

I want the javascript array to be something like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

json_encode is what your looking for,

```
var needHelp = <?php echo json_encode($needHelp1); ?>
```

When you run your php check the source and you should have a javascript array.

Comment: I didn't notice the output format you wanted.  Construct your array the way you want it then json_encode.